# Number of class element

Tags: javascript, html

i can have many elements within one class for example:

```
<input class='example' id='one' ...onclick="setURL(urls[0])"
<input class='example' id='two' ...onclick="setURL(urls[1])"
<input class='example' id='three' ...onclick="setURL(urls[2])"
 ....
```

urls[] is an array with strings to different html pages.
if i write  something like:

```
var all = document.getElementByClassName('example');
```

all.length is then 2. Is there any possibility to transfer the number from the var all into the from the vector urls[]?
Something like this:

```
    <input class='example' id='one' ...onclick="setURL(this.all)"
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? To pass all urls in `setURL`?

Comment: Sry, was a mistake, i mean: setURL(urls[all.this])

Comment: why not just use .value to assign the count to an input? Also - no inline js!!!

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be better to generate the HTML itself within a loop in your javascript code? that way you should have more option to do what you want?

something like this, for instance:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ybqzoy

```
(function() {
  var i, key, len, list, t, val;

  list = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

  for (key = i = 0, len = list.length; i < len; key = ++i) {if (window.CP.shouldStopExecution(1)){break;}
    val = list[key];
    t = "<div class='example' id='" + val + "' onClick='setUrl(urls[" + key + "])'>" + val + "</div>";
    $('#res').append(t);
    console.log("t is " + t);
  }
window.CP.exitedLoop(1);


}).call(this);
```